# Pattern Matching Types Out Of Strings in F#

Tags: f#

I am working on a function that pattern matches some of my user-defined types in f# and converts them to strings. Part of the code looks like the following:

```
let gsToString (gs : general_structure) : string = 
    match gs with
    | Date(Scattered(Eom(Ascending))) -> "Date(Scattered(Eom(Ascending)))"
    | Date(Scattered(Eom(SameDate(dt)))) -> "Date(Scattered(Eom(SameDate(" + dt.ToString() + "))))"
    | Number(AllNegative(Int1(Neither))) -> "Number(AllNegative(Int1(Neither)))" 
    | Number(AllNegative(Int1(SameInt(si)))) -> "Number(AllNegative(Int1(SameFloat(" + si.ToString() + "))))"
```

There are many other types being matched in this function, but these should be enough to convey the issue. Additionally, the types causing problems are:

```
| SameDate of System.DateTime
| SameFloat of float
```

Obviously, It is pretty trivial to do the first pattern matching function that converts my general_structure types to strings. However, a problem arises in my next function (which needs to be called later on in the code), where I need to reconvert the string representation back to a general_structure. The problem areas look like the following:

```
let stringToGS (str : string) : general_structure = 
    match str with
    | "Date(Scattered(Eom(Ascending)))" -> Date(Scattered(Eom(Ascending)))
    | "Date(Scattered(Eom(SameDate(dt))))"-> Date(Scattered(Eom(SameDate(System.DateTime.Parse dt))))
    | "Number(AllNegative(Int1(Neither)))" -> Number(AllNegative(Int1(Neither))) 
    | "Number(AllPositive(Float1(SameFloat(sf))))" -> Number(AllPositive(Float1(SameFloat((float) sf))))
```

Although the first and the third cases in the stringToGS function work just fine, I am unable to find a way to convert the others back to their original form. If there any way to take a string inside of a pattern matching statement (in this case it would be dt and fs) and somehow parse only that portion of the pattern in order to return a different value (in this case I am trying to make them System.DateTimes and Floats, respectively) and return then to their original forms of:

```
Date(Scattered(Eom(SameDate(dt))))
Number(AllPositive(Float1(SameFloat(sf))))
```

? I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I was able to resolve the problem by doing something like the following with if statements for the cases that were causing problems:

```
if str.Contains("Scattered(Eom(SameDate")
then 
    let p1 = str.IndexOf(")")
    let p2 = str.LastIndexOf("(")
    let dt1 = str.Remove(p1)
    let dt2 = dt1.Substring(p2 + 1)
    let date = System.DateTime.Parse dt2
    Date(Scattered(Eom(SameDate(date))))
```

Then, I could just do the normal pattern matching on all of the types that did not contain nested data.

Comment: Does the string format need to look as the one in your sample? If no, you could perhaps use some existing serialization library like: http://nessos.github.io/FsPickler/

Comment: yeah thought about FsPickler too - but AFAIK there is no F#-syntax-like format included - XML and JSON are of course there

Comment: @Carsten Yeah I realize that was a pretty stupid idea on my part.

Comment: I will look into some serialization

Comment: @AveryB sorry this comment probably was rather negative and rather rude - but maybe if you tell us what you are trying to achieve with this (do you want to persist the data?) we can give you more positive advice ...

Comment: @Carsten no worries! I found a workaround that is slightly annoying, but it gets the job done. I edited the question to reflect the change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use active patterns, if there is a limited amount of classes and you don't want to use a serialization library:

```
open System

let (|RegexMatch|_|) pattern input =
    let matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
    if matches.Count = 1 then Some matches.[0].Groups.[1].Value
    else None

type GeneralStructure =
| NoPayload
| DatePayload of DateTime
| StringPayload of string option

let toString = function
| NoPayload -> "NoPayload"
| DatePayload dt -> sprintf "DatePayload(%d)" <| dt.ToBinary()
| StringPayload None -> "StringPayload(None)"
| StringPayload (Some s) -> sprintf "StringPayload(Some(%s))" s

let fromString = function
| "NoPayload" -> NoPayload
| "StringPayload(None)" -> StringPayload None
| RegexMatch @"DatePayload\((.*)\)" dt -> DatePayload <| DateTime.FromBinary(Int64.Parse dt)
| RegexMatch @"StringPayload\(Some\((.*)\)\)" msg -> StringPayload <| Some msg
| o -> failwithf "Unknown %s %s" typeof<GeneralStructure>.Name o


let serialized = StringPayload <| Some "Foo" |> toString
let deserialized = fromString serialized

let serialized' = DatePayload DateTime.UtcNow |> toString
let deserialized' = fromString serialized'

// val serialized : string = "StringPayload(Some(Foo))"
// val deserialized : GeneralStructure = StringPayload (Some "Foo")
// val serialized' : string = "DatePayload(5247430828937321388)"
// val deserialized' : GeneralStructure = DatePayload 06.08.2015 18:04:10
```

Note that the regex is not foolproof, I made that up just to fit these cases.